# How to map one class properties to another using class with different names using CsvClassMap

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, csv, csvhelper

My application reads .CSV file(which do not having a header in csv file) and converts into XML file.
For existing code wrote as

```
sr = new StreamReader(fs);
fs = null;

using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(sr))
{
    sr = null;

    csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = hasHeaderRecord;
    csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = false;
    csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreReadingExceptions = true;
    csvReader.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
    csvReader.Configuration.TrimFields = true;

    csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<Class1Map>();
    FileRecords = csvReader.GetRecords<Class1>().ToList();
}


public class Class1Map : CsvClassMap<Class1>
    {
        public Class1Map()
        {
            Map(m => m.AccountId).Index(0);
            Map(m => m.MeterId).Index(1);
            .......
            .......
        }
     }
```

But now for my new requirement, .csv file includes header and column names that are different compared to previous .csv. Somehow I have read the new CSV file and get values present in the csv file and mapped to class1.

Class1 properties are AccountId,MeterId etc.
But in new format the names are different now.
AccountId as AccountRef and MeterId as MeterSerial.

Can any one suggest how to map new file values of AccountRef,MeterSerial to class1 properties AccountId,MeterId

Comment: Can you thinking about include all properties. `AccountId`,`MeterId`,`AccountRef`, `MeterSerial` Then use TopLevel Property or Method for get to value. Value calculate like this `Account { get { return AccountId ?? AccountRef } }`

Comment: Thank you @EminNiftiyev. I will think the way you suggested. In my mind, I have approach as  I have to create a new class 'class 2' with new properties and trying map as like class1 approach. Then class2 and class1 mapping.

Comment: Can use AutoMapper? on your project?

Comment: What is in your Class1Map now? Does your constructor have `Map(m => m.AccountId).Name("AccountRef");` etc?

Comment: @EminNiftiyev. ok. I will try with AutoMapper. Let you know once completed

Comment: You can use [CsvHelper's Attributes](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/attributes/) to map from the CSV headers to properties

Comment: Thank you for reply @rene. My map class as public class Class1Map : CsvClassMap<Class1>
    {
        public Class1Map()
        {
            Map(m => m.AccountId).Index(0);
            Map(m => m.MeterId).Index(1);
            .......
            .......
        }
     }

Comment: And that doesn't work? How does it fail?

Comment: Hi @rene      This map class is existing one. New csv file do not have proper order to retrieve based on index. So, I have taken values by reading header only

Comment: Instead of `Index` use the header name then as I have shown in earlier comment. hasHeaderRecord = true, right?

Comment: @rene hasHeaderRecord is true. I will test

Comment: @rene. thank you. I tried as you suggested. I am able read values from new CSV file and assign to old class1 properties. i.e. Map(m => m.AccountId).Name("AccountRef")

Comment: @MindSwipe
Thank you for your suggestion. your link helped in implementing of my task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add `.Name()` to your maps.  Your first example with no header will use `.Index()` and your second example with a header will use `.Name()` to map the columns.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config1 = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false
    };

    using (var reader = new StringReader("1,2\n3,4"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config1))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<Class1Map>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Class1>().Dump();
    }

    var config2 = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = true
    };

    using (var reader = new StringReader("MeterSerial,AccountRef\n4,5\n6,7"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config2))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<Class1Map>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Class1>().Dump();
    }
}

public class Class1Map : ClassMap<Class1>
{
    public Class1Map()
    {
        Map(m => m.AccountId).Index(0).Name("AccountRef");
        Map(m => m.MeterId).Index(1).Name("MeterSerial");
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int MeterId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @David Specht , Can suggest me how to set default values when MeterID property in new class is always empty. Customer do not provide value OR header also in CSV file. I have to set default value as empty to MeterID always.

Comment: You could use `Optional()` and `Default()`.  Optional means they don't have to include the header.  Default will provide a default value if one isn't give. `Map(m => m.MeterId).Index(1).Name("MeterSerial").Optional().Default(10);`

Comment: Also, if this answers your question, it will be helpful for others if you accept the answer.

Comment: I marked as answer.

Comment: Hi @David Specht....I am using CSPHelper version 2.0. I am not getting optional(). I used default("") for my bool property awalys empy. But it is populated with null. and int property with 0. Some of my properties must be empty. New file did not provide values. So, we will initialize empty always for new CSV file. could you suggest the approach

Comment: That's a really old version of CsvHelper.  It probably didn't have the `Optional()` option.  Can you upgrade to a newer version?